# Phonegap Android with TestFlight SDK, sessions are not tracked

Tags: android, cordova, testflight

I have a Phonegap 3.0 Android app, with the TestFlight SDK integrated.

The TestFlight website recognized my app has the SDK embedded (green check mark shows in the SDK column, on the build version line).
Yet, the TestFlight website doesn't show the user sessions when the app is in use.

Here is how I implemented it:

The documentation specified I should use this code

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    //Initialize TestFlight with your app token.
    TestFlight.takeOff(this, YOUR_APP_TOKEN);
    ...
  }
}
```

In Phonegap the class actually extends `DroidGap` (which is not an application).
So I had to do instead

```
TestFlight.takeOff(this.getApplication(), TEST_FLIGHT_APP_TOKEN);
```

Also, it says AndroidManifest.xml should have

```
<application ... android:name="MyApplication">
```

When I add that (pointing to my main class (the one which extends DroidGap) I get an exception when the app loads `java.lang.ClassCastException` casting from my main class to `android.app.Application`

It looks like there should be a main class that extends `Application`, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4):

You should setup a *separate* java class in your project that extends Application, and call takeOff in onCreate

```
     public class MyApplication extends Application { 

              @Override 
                 public void onCreate() { 
                     TestFlight.takeOff(this, YOUR_APP_TOKEN);
                     super.onCreate(); 
                 } 

     }
```

You should not put the name of your Activity (which extends DroidGap) in the Application tag of the manifest, as this will cause a ClassCastException. Instead, use the name of the class extending Application, in this example "MyApplication".

Comment: Followed these instructions and got one session to show on the TestFlight site once!. No more sessions are logged from the same device, or other devices with the same, or later builds. When debugging  I can see the log says "TestFlight takeOff complete. Version: 1.0"
Any idea?

Comment: Also the TestFlight site confirms the build has the SDK.

Comment: Did you sign your build with a debug or release certificate? You need to sign with debug for session data to show up in TestFlight. Also make sure that your testing with the exact build that was uploaded to TestFlight.

Comment: Also you can run this command to check what cert was used to sign the build: jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs app_file.apk